# Error while installing SQL Server Express 2012 on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

I receive the folowing error while I try to install SQL Server Express 2012 on Windows 7 Ultimate :

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Setup

The following error has occurred:

Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%25400xBB814387

---

BUTTONS:

&Retry

### Cancel

I also tried to install SQL Server express 2008. This installation gives a similar error with: "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.".

Does anyone know what can be the cause of this?

Thanks a lot!

Marcel

Comment: Going out on a limb, but do you need to run setup as an admin? (Did that a long time ago, but I am sure it asks for the elevated privileges though).

Comment: You mean I did run setup as an admin and I should not?

Comment: Not saying that you should not. Rather that you should, but you may not have to.

Comment: I have tried to run as administrator bij right clicking the downloaded SQL Server file, although the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

answer from @Shanky :

1.open Run type 'regedit'

2.go to this path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server.

3.Right click and go to Permission.

4.Click on Advance

5.Tick on both check box (I. Inherit from parent the permission... II. Replace permission entries on all child objects...).

6.click OK

7.Click OK again
Hopefully this might solve your issue

Comment: I will try this. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains the same.

Comment: I cant use... please say why set number 5??